# Removing leading spaces/newlines left from unchecked Multi-Select box

Tags: reporting-services, multi-select

I have a multi-select box with 15-20 values in it corresponding to SharePoint users. The problem I'm having is that for every entry in the Multi-Select box that is not chosen, a new line or blank line placeholder gets placed in the output. So when I'm pulling this stuff into SSRS, I'm getting a bunch of empty lines and Trim, LTrim, RTrim aren't working. Tried replacing VBCRLF with "", and a bunch of other stuff with no luck. Here is what the output looks like:

[image: screenshot]